# Download data from OpenStreetMap that is not in English gives wrongs characters

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, unicode, hebrew

I have download data from OSM from Israel area but whenever I open the data in QGIS I am getting wrong characters and it doesn´t show Hebrew, even though on OSM it does show it in Hebrew. I know there is option to play with the Unicode but I don´t see this option in QGIS. Is there any way to change the Unicode of layers downloaded from OSM before opening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the properties of your layer (right click the layer)

[image]

You can adjust the data source encoding there.